# How to draw a small benzene ring symbol in an inline chemical formula?

Tags: symbols, chemistry

I need to type an inline chemical formula such as HO-(C=O)-([Benzene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzene))-(C=O)-OH. Is there a way I could insert a small benzene symbol (something compact, without using `tikzpicture` environment, `\schemestart...\schemestop` etc.)?

I know there's a [unicode symbol](http://unicode-table.com/en/232C/) but I couldn't make it work, nor do I think it's optimal.

Right now I have:

```
HO-\stackrel{\stackrel{O}{||}}{C}-Bz-\stackrel{\stackrel{O}{||}}{C}-OH
```

Where "Bz" is where the benzene symbol should go.

Comment: Not everyone is acquainted with chemistry. The expected output and a minimal working example (MWE) are appreciated.

Comment: The wasysym package has a hexagon symbol.  You may need to adjust it to look good.

Comment: AFAIK there is no `chemfig` environment?! But the `\chemfig` macro has optional arguments which allow scaling. Other than that simply C6H4 would of course work...

Comment: @clemens, question updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the `\smallbenz`, I stack a `\circ` inside of a `\hexagon`.  I then use `\scalerel*` to make it an appropriate size, which I arbitrarily chose as `.8\baselineskip` tall, shifted down by `.2\baselineskip` for centering.  Those values can be changed.

EDITED to lessen the vertical stacking gap to 2pt.  RE-EDITED to provide a 2nd possibility, with dashes inserted around the inside of a hexagon.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,wasysym,scalerel}
\newcommand\wrule[3][0pt]{\textcolor{white}{\rule[#1]{#2}{#3}}}
\def\smallbenz{\scalerel*{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-.25pt}{$\circ$}{\hexagon}}{%
  \rule[-.2\baselineskip]{1pt}{.8\baselineskip}}}
\setstackgap{S}{2pt}
\begin{document}
HO$-$\stackon{C}{\stackon{$||$}{O}}$-$%
  \smallbenz%
  $-$\stackon{C}{\stackon{$||$}{O}}$-$OH

\vspace{2em}
\def\smallbenz{\scalerel*{\kern-3pt%
\stackinset{c}{0.95pt}{b}{2.2pt}{-}{%
\rotatebox[origin=center]{120}{\stackinset{c}{-0.4pt}{b}{.3pt}{-}{%
\rotatebox[origin=center]{120}{\stackinset{c}{.24pt}{b}{-1.5pt}{-}{%
  \hexagon}}}}}}{\rule[-.75\baselineskip]{1pt}{2\baselineskip}}\kern-3pt}
%
HO$-$\stackon{C}{\stackon{$||$}{O}}$-$%
  \smallbenz%
  $-$\stackon{C}{\stackon{$||$}{O}}$-$OH
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could use `\chemfig`:

```
\usepackage{chemfig}
\def\smallbenz{\raisebox{0.2em}%
   {\chemfig[scale=0.18][scale=0.18]{[:-30]**6(------)}}}

\textnormal{HO}-\smallbenz-\textnormal{OH}
```

[image]

Comment: this is pretty neat, and you gave me an idea: `\def\smallbenz{\chemfig[scale=0.15][scale=0.15]{[:-30]**6(------)}}`. The problem is that when I use it it's not aligned to the middle of the line, i.e. if I type `-\smallbenz-`, the dashes are at the level of the top of the benzene... ideas?

Comment: @Sparkler Could you apply a `\raisebox{length}{\chemfig{...}}`?